# How to unlock a secret game in Angry Birds Space

Tags: angry-birds-space

Is the rumor true that I have heard that by accessing some secret golden egg in Angry Birds Space, I can go to a completely new place where there's a little bonus Atari breakout game. Can somebody tell me where is it? Or is there no such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here (with video)](https://www.angrybirdsnest.com/angry-birds-space-golden-eggsteroid-3-walkthrough/):

> Golden Eggsteroid #3 is located on level 2-13 of Angry Birds Space Cold Cuts. Zoom out to see the Golden Eggsteroid in the brush on the planet below the slingshot platform. Launch the Lazer bird backwards, then redirect him into the Eggsteroid to snatch it. Once you hit the egg you’ll immediately be transported via a wormhole to the level, which pays homage to the 1970’s video game Breakout.